# The Crtl+Q is not working in Android studio?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is not working in Android studio? I have set up the source code and I can view the source code.  But just cannot use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to view the doc.

You can see in the picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem, because I'm in China! What I did is: click "File -> Open Moudle Setting ",open teh `Project Structure`,click `SDKs`->`Doucmentation Paths`, remove the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing and reopening Android Studio. This happened to me briefly, earlier. My problem was remedied by a simple program restart.